# How to insert data into a list in recursive Prolog

Tags: prolog

Trying to figure out how to return a list which contains ancestors of person A until person B. For example, I have the following facts:

```
parent(john,paul).
parent(paul,henry).
parent(henry,helen).
```

I can use the following code to find the ancestor of Y

```
ancestor(X,Y):-parent(X,Y).
ancestor(X,Y):-parent(X,Z), ancestor(Z,Y).
```

And I want to have a function `list(X,Y,L)` which will return the list of ancestors between `X`, `Y`.
Ex, `List(john,helen,L)` will return `L = [paul, henry]`

Based on the previous code, I know the Z is the value needed. But I do not know how to insert these value into a list and return.

I tried this but does not work as expected:

```
list([]).
ancestorList(X,Y,L):- parent(X,Y).
ancestorList(X,Y,L):- parent(P,Y), list(Old), L = [P | Old], ancestorList(X,P,L).
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So other "brances" are ignored (parent relations that never end up to `Y`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it must hold that

```erlang
ancestorList( john, helen, L) :- L = [paul, henry], L = [paul | [henry      ] ].
```

then it must also hold that

```erlang
ancestorList( paul, helen, L) :- L = [      henry], L =         [henry | [] ]  .  % and,

ancestorList( henry, helen, L) :- L =                                    []    .
```

But we also know that

```erlang
ancestorList( henry, helen, L) :- parent( henry, helen),  L =            []    .
```

Thus we know that

```erlang
%           Parent, Child, List
ancestorList( Henry, Helen, L) :- parent( Henry, Helen),  L =            []    .

%      Ancestor, Descendant, List
ancestorList( Paul,  Helen, L) :- parent( Paul, Henry),   L =   [ Paul |  T ]  ,
                                  ancestorList( Henry, Helen,             T  ) .
```

This will create the list which is almost what you want. You can make it be exactly so by changing one name in the above definition.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the answer with the wrong order. How can I insert data into the back of each list? If I use the function L = [P|L] which means everytime the new parent found will be inserted into the beginning of the list. I tried to use append and it does not work append(L, [P], L).

Comment: All you need to change in the last code is one name. Look closely, which one do you want in the list. There's also a concrete example above it. I could tell you, but it's better if you see it yourself. You do realize that `henry` is a concrete piece of data, an atom (and a child of `paul`), and `Henry` (or `Paul`) is a logical variable, right? You could rename the logical variables as you please, as long as the renaming is consistent. But I used *those* names as they follow the concrete examples shown at the top.

Comment: Aha, I see, the part i missed is I changed two name which make the inserted sequence in opposite order,I used  parent(Henry, Paul), instead or  parent( Paul, Henry). Really appreciated for your help.

Comment: great! now rename to normal names, like Parent, Child, Ancestor and Descendant!

Answer (score 3):

Based on your approach, you - like many other people that start working in Prolog - aim to program in Prolog as an "imperative language".

In Prolog you can not *reassign* a variable. If you write `L = []`, then this means that, unless you *backtrack*, `L` will always be the empty list. So calling `L = [P|Old]` later on, will result in `false`, since unficiation will never yield that `[]` and `[_|_]` are equal.

You thus can not "create" a list by first initializing it to `[]` and then later "altering" it, since altering is (or well should) not be possible. There are some noteworthy exceptions (like adding facts with `assert/1`, but these are typically "bad design").

Before implementing a predicate, it is better to first design an *inductive definition* that specifies the logical relation you aim to implement. Then you can translate this definition into a predicate.

An inductive definition here could look like:

1. The `ancestorList(X, Z, L)` of two persons `X` and `Z` is `[X]` given `parent(X, Z)` holds; and
2. The `ancestorList(X, Y, L)` of two persons `X` and `Y` is a list that starts with `X` given `parent(X, Y)` hols, and the rest of the list is the `ancestorList/3` of `Y` up to `Z`.

Once we have this inductive definition, we can translate this into code. The "skeleton" of this look like:

```
ancestorList(X, Z, ___):-
    ___.
ancestorList(X, Z, ___) :-
    parent(X, Y),
    ___.
```

with the `___` that still need to be filled in.

Given there aren no *infinite* `parent/2` chains, we know that this program will not get stuck in an infinite loop, and eventually fail if there is no chain of parents between the two given ones.

Answer (score 0):

A *minimal edit* fix to your code, while following the `ancestor` predicate as you indeed wanted to, could be

```ml
% (* ancestor(X,Y) :- parent(X,Y). *)
% (* ancestor(X,Y) :- parent(X,Z), ancestor(Z,Y). *)

ancestor_list(X,Y,L) :- parent(X,Y), L = [].
ancestor_list(X,Y,L) :- parent(X,Z), L = [Z | Next], ancestor_list(Z,Y,Next).
```

The *Prolog* way of building lists is top-down, not just bottom-up like in most other functional languages (it can do *that* too, but top-down is neater, more efficient). So we indeed "insert" the value, `Z`, at the *top* of the list `L = [Z | Next]` being built, and the recursive call `ancestor_list(Z,Y,Next)` completes that `Next` list until the base case which ends it with the `[]` as it should, thus creating the list

```ml
[Z1 ,  Z2 ,  Z3 , ...., ZN              ]
[Z1 | [Z2 | [Z3 | .... [ZN | []] .... ]]]
      Next1
            Next2 ....
                       NextN_1                 % (N-1)th Next
                             NextN
```

after `N` recursive calls. The list itself is *not* "returned" from the last recursive call, but it is *set up* by the very *first* call, and the rest of the recursive calls finish "setting" (*unifying*, really) its elements up one by one.

See also:

- [Tail recursion modulo cons](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Tail_call&oldid=979629785#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons)
- [tailrecursion-modulo-cons](/questions/tagged/tailrecursion-modulo-cons) [tag-info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tailrecursion-modulo-cons/info)